# PHP Remove ID and Title from URL ( reading from DB )

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove id and title from url, example:

```txt
http://example.com/item.php?id=123?title=radna-odela
```

The second parameter is from database name "alias".

I want to be:

```txt
http://example.com/item/123/radna-odela
```

Also, I will need exactly for "categories.php".

I have this code and its working only for an item, I can't add more, it will just break...

```txt
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([0-9]+)/([a-z\-A-Z]+)
RewriteRule (.*) item.php?id=%1&title=%2 [L]
```

Comment: Look into using some router library. They are usually easier to use and you can define the rules directly in your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^(item|categories)/([0-9]+)/([a-z\-A-Z]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule should look something like that

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([0-9]+)/([a-z\-A-Z]+)
RewriteRule ^item/(.*)/(.*) item.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

And then you had some rules as you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&]+)&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]
```